# Removing single quotes if they aren't in the middle of a word

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to remove all punctuation and single quotes ' from a string, unless the single quote ' is in the middle of a word.

At this point I have the following code:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()
        line = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", line)
        print line
```

if there happens to be a line in test.txt like:

```
Here is some stuff. 'Now there are quotes.' Now there's not.
```

The result I want is:

```
here is some stuff now there are quotes now there's not
```

But the result I get is:

```
here is some stuff 'now there are quotes' now there's not
```

How can I remove the single quotes ' from a string if they're at the beginning or end of the word but not in the middle? Thanks for the help!

Comment: May I recomend https://www.debuggex.com/.

Comment: try  >> re.sub("(^')|('$)", "", line)

Comment: What about `"The kids' toys?"`

Comment: `kids' toys` -> `kids toys` since the apostrophe isn't in the middle of the word. Not perfect english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string, use `strip()` on each word to remove leading and trailing characters on it, then join it all back together.

```
>>> s = "'here is some stuff 'now there are quotes' now there's not'"
>>> print(' '.join(w.strip("'") for w in s.split()).lower())
here is some stuff now there are quotes now there's not
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've maybe used a better example. The single quotes aren't necessarily at the beginning and end of the line. The string could look like:
`This is the string. 'Now there are quotes!' Now there's not.`
And I want it to look like:
`this is the string now there are quotes now there's not`

I believe strip() wouldn't work in this context? (edited the question to reflect this)

Comment: I would like to know what is wrong with this answer that it deserves downvotes. Then I can improve it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yours isn't the only one. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, you could first remove `'`s that don't follow a letter, then remove `'`s that don't precede a letter (thus only keeping ones that both follow and precede a letter):

```
line = "Here is some stuff. 'Now there are quotes.' Now there's not."
print re.sub(r"'([^A-Za-z])", r"\1", re.sub(r"([^A-Za-z])'", r"\1", line))
# Here is some stuff. Now there are quotes. Now there's not.
```

Probably more efficient to do it @TigerhawkT3's way. Though they produce different results if you have something like `'this'.` If you want to remove that second `'` too, then the regular expressions method is probably the simplest you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using regular expressions with [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
This method will preserve any whitespace your string may have.

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)\'|\'(?!\w)")
# Regex explanation:
# (?<!\w)\'    match any quote not preceded by a word
# |            or
# \'(?!\w)     match any quote not followed by a word
s = "'here is some stuff 'now there are quotes' now there's not'"
print rgx.sub('', s)  # here is some stuff now there are quotes now there's not
```

Answer (score 0):

If a word is a sequence of 1+ letters, digits and underscores that can be matched with `\w+` you may use

```
re.sub(r"(?!\b'\b)'", "", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPnVna/1). Here, `'` is matched when it is not preceded nor followed with letters/digits/`_`.

Or, if words are strictly linguistic words that only consist of letters, use

```
re.sub(r"'(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z]')[a-zA-Z])", "", text) # ASCII only
re.sub(r"'(?!(?<=[^\W\d_]')[^\W\d_])", "", text) # any Unicode letter support
```

See [Demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/VPnVna/2) (ASCII only letters) and [Demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/VPnVna/3) (see last line in the demo text). Here, `'` is only matched if it is not preceded nor followed with a letter (ASCII or any).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/tYz8UD):

```
import re
text = "'text... 'some quotes', there's none'. three 'four' can't, '2'4',  '_'_', 'l'école'"
print( re.sub(r"(?!\b'\b)'", "", text) )
# => text... some quotes, there's none. three four can't, 2'4,  _'_, l'école
print( re.sub(r"'(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z]')[a-zA-Z])", "", text) )
# => text... some quotes, there's none. three four can't, 24,  __, lécole
print( re.sub(r"'(?!(?<=[^\W\d_]')[^\W\d_])", "", text) )
# => text... some quotes, there's none. three four can't, 24,  __, l'école
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is complete solution to remove whatever you don't want in a string:

```
def istext (text):
    ok = 0
    for x in text: ok += x.isalnum()
    return ok>0

def stripit (text, ofwhat):
    for x in ofwhat: text = text.strip(x)
    return text

def purge (text, notwanted="'\"!#$%&/()=?*+-.,;:_<>|\\[]{}"):
    text = text.splitlines()
    text = [" ".join([stripit(word, notwanted) for word in line.split() if istext(word)]) for line in text]
    return "\n".join(text)

>>> print purge("'Nice, .to, see! you. Isn't it?'")
```

Nice to see you Isn't it

Note: this will kill all whitespaces too and transform them to space or remove them completely.

Comment: Hahahahahaha, accepted answer that is perfectly in order gets down voted. Nice!