# replace (not remove) a character with condition

Tags: python, regex

How do I use the `replace` function to replace all instances with the exception of one.

```
mystr = "he said: 'hi my name's Jim'."
mystr.replace("'", '"')
print(mystr)
```

The output I would want is:
`he said: "hi my name's Jim".`

How do I exclude `'s` from the replace? ie exclude all `'` followed by an `s` and where the `'` is preceded by digit/letter.

if `mystr2 = "'s: hi'"` then I wouldn't want to replace the first `'` only replace the second `'`.

**UPDATE**
[Removing single quotes if they aren't in the middle of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635909/removing-single-quotes-if-they-arent-in-the-middle-of-a-word)
This shows how to remove the required quotes, but not how to replace it.

Comment: Removing is the same as replacing in this regard. Just replace the `""` in the replacement with the required replacement. Choose from [three solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337375/3832970).

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034821/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach would be to use this regex:

```
\B'\b|\b'\B
```

and replace with `"`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY22Cf/1)

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\B`: inverse of `\b` or word boundary

```sh
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "he said: 'hi my name's Jim'."
>>> print (re.sub(r"\B'\b|\b'\B", '"', mystr))
he said: "hi my name's Jim".
```

Answer (score 0):

another regex: `'(?!s)` replaces every `'` that is *not* followed by a `s`

```
import re
mystr = "he said: 'hi my name's Jim'."
newstr = re.sub(r"'(?!s)", '"', mystr)
print(newstr)
```

output:
`he said: "hi my name's Jim".`